# Inset Tool Modal Map missing

Tags: customization, shortcut

For speeding my modeling workflow I created a ergonomic keymap explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyvVZv_nD94).
But the inset tool doesn't have the Modal map like the knife tool. Which allows you to remap his shortcut when activated. How can I access or create this option?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here you go just search for keypress and the letter " i " in the search box.
You will find it under mesh category.

[image]

Comment: Hi guys, thanks but what i'm talking about is be able to modify the shortcut of the inset properties ( Change boundary offset Even,etc) like in the knife tool: [knife modal http://i.imgur.com/TVlFtGD.png

Comment: No worry man thanks for taking the time to answer me ;).

Comment: You may want to paste that knife modal image from your first comment on your original post , I think it's much clearer at saying what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add or change keyboard shortcuts by hovering your mouse over the context in the toolshelf, and by pressing  <kbd>RMB</kbd> ,
then choose *add (or change) shortcut* and enter the desired short cut in the pop up box. Don't forget to save your new shortcut as default by going to *user preferences>save user settings.* [image]